# Sitecore Experience Editor Publish Menu

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am trying to publish entire site from experience editor. However publish option in Home menu only showing up **Publish Item Dialog**. Is there any way I can publish site from experience editor.

The reason is my current item has sublayouts with datasources at different folders in sitecore tree. When I do publish Item, item changes get published along with images however changes made to datasources in item doesn't reflect in publish site.

I am publishing items with sub items and related items check box ticked and as per documentation from sitecore it only publishes alias, media and clone references. But datasources changes on item doesn't get published.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are your datasources in workflow? Are they in an approved state prior to you publishing? I've seen that issue cause datasources not to get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch to the Core database
2. Open the Content Editor
3. Navigate to /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page
   Editor/Publish/Publish
4. Duplicate this item
5. Change the value of the "Click" field to "system:publish(id=$Target)", the value of "Header" to "Publish Site" and the value of "Tooltip" to "Publish the current item."
6. Switch to the Master database

Open the Experience Editor and you will be able to see the "Publish Site" button on the ribbon.

Comment: Anton and Dmytro Thanks! for your response I have tried steps as mentioned below however it only showing up Publish Item Dialog. I am using SItecore 8.1 Update 2